# Get Current Domain from Unity Configuration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a Service that makes API calls to an external App using the executing domain. So if I am in test mode, I call "http://localhost" and if I am in Production I would like it call a different address. So far I have

```
    public interface IMyService{
       void DoStuff();
    }

    private string _url;
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {

    public MyService(string ExecutingDomainAddress)
    {
       _url = ExecutingDomainAddress;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
      var destination = _url + "/GetCustomers";
    }

    }
```

In my Unity Configuration I have defined my Service and Contract as

```
container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>();
```

I would like to inject the current url/address into the Service constructor. Can that be done from here?
So for example:

```
var theCurrenDomain = "http://localhost/MySite"; //I want this to be dynamically generated e.g. Request.Url.Authority
container.RegisterInstance<string>("ExecutingDomainAddress", theCurrenDomain, new PerThreadLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<string>("ExecutingDomainAddress")));
```

How do I get the url from here and apply it to the "theCurrentDomain" variable?

Comment: Are you sure this is ASP.NET MVC 4? That's extremely old. It's more likely you're using .NET 4.x and MVC 5.x

Comment: My bad you are correct. I have selected the wrong tags

Comment: You really didn't need to tag this with asp.net-mvc-5 anyways. This code would perform the same exact way in a console app, so there's nothing specific  to the MVC framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to create a class to represent these settings, then register that class as a type. Then any classes that depend on those settings can request an object of that type via constructor injection.

```
container.RegisterType<FileSystemPricerStagingDirectorySettings>(new InjectionConstructor(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PricerStagingDirectory"]));

container.RegisterType<IPricerStagingRepository, FileSystemPricerStagingRepository>();

public FileSystemPricerStagingRepository(FileSystemPricerStagingDirectorySettings pricerStagingDirectorySettings)
{
    // now I can get what I need from pricerStagingDirectorySettings
}
```

Comment: OK cool. But how do I read the current url in place of your ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PricerStagingDirectory"]? I'd know what it is up front, but I'd rather not have to add it to my web.config

Comment: Then don't add it to your web.config. You can do whatever you want there. If you hardcode it, or have a variable, or read it from somewhere else, it will accept it. All it needs is a string. I happen to get mine from the .config file, that doesn't mean you have to.

Comment: This got me close enough to what I needed. Cheers